# Philosophical aliens without arms quickly create an industrial world using monkeys

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a philosophical short story I read in the 80s.

On an alien planet the most intellectually advanced beings are creatures with no arms and one foot to hop around on.

They are highly intelligent but have no civilization or technology, or even ability to make things. They just lie around in the sun philosophising and speculating about things, imagining how they might do them in theory only.

One day one of them has as idea and somehow manages to tame a number of monkey-like creatures, stupid but dexterous with their hands. He has them make physical examples of some of his mental inventions.

Over a very short period of time the planet is completely industrialised. Their technology advances by leaps and bounds because they already had plans for everything worked out in principle.

At the end of the story an individual sits on a hill watching a spaceship launch and wonders if they wouldn't have been happier as they were.

I remember this as having a bit of a fable vibe to it.

Edit: I'm pretty certain about the one foot and hopping around. That bit stuck in my mind.

Comment: Are you sure they tame the monkey creatures as opposed to telepathically controlling them?

Comment: @DavidW Possibly, I don't remember how it was done just that they did it.

Comment: @DavidW - and they were centaurs, not one-legged...

Comment: Sounds like "Second Dawn" by Arthur C. Clarke, described in this old Q&A. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66305/which-70s-80s-story-book-has-horses-as-protagonists/66307#66307 Is that it?

Comment: @user14111 I don't know about OP, but that's the one _I_ was thinking of. :)

Comment: Actually I'm very certain about the one foot and hopping around. Also I don't think there was anything about a war. The creatures weren't that motivated to begin with

Comment: @PotatoCrisp From Clarke's ["Second Dawn"](https://archive.org/details/Science_Fiction_Quarterly_New_Series_v01n02_1951-08/page/n103/mode/2up): Their sleek, fur-covered bodies tapered to a single giant rear-limb that could send them leaping over the ground in thirty-foot bounds. The two forelimbs were much smaller, and served merely for support and steadying. They ended in pointed hoofs that could be deadly in combat, but had no other useful purpose.

Comment: @user14111  "Second Dawn" has similar ideas, and I may have mis-remembered/forgotten a lot, but I remember what I read as a much simpler story with fewer characters, more of a little parable. I wonder is there was an older short version of this that Clarke could have developed into "Second Dawn".